# Regex numeric range with no leading zeros

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate this pattern:

1.1.1.1 up to 254.254.254.254, but with no leading zeros. so 001.001.001.001 should not match.

I have

```
/^([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])\.([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$/
```

but this matches the leading zeros.  Can anyone recommend how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Each element will be:

```
[1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4]
```

Breakdown of parts:

```
(1-99)      (100-199)   (200-249)   (250-254)
```

Oh, and one other thing I should mention...  You need to handle the number `0` in the 2nd, 3rd and 4rd places.  So just put an extra option for a single `0` digit in those groups.  I don't think it's valid to have a zero as the first number in an IP address (although it is valid if it's a mask).

Comment: closest thing to an answer, but it did not validate either. http://regex101.com/r/xI8yF2 only grabs the 25 in 254

Comment: You didn't put parentheses around it.  You must place the `^` and `$` outside the parentheses and the rest inside.  Same as in your original question.

Comment: Note that I have edited my answer to point out that you still need to handle `0` -- assuming that you are trying to recognise IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

For repeating patterns like this, it's handy to use numbered repetition.  The following should match what you're after

```
([1-9]\d{0,3}\.){3}[1-9]\d{0,3}
```

EDIT: I'm asleep and missed the part to cap at .254.  I'll update when I get a chance.

Comment: Writing regular expressions in your sleep is hardcore!

Comment: The cap is the hard part I originally tried this same thing, but it needs a cap AND no leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
^(([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4]))\.(?1)\.(?1)\.(?1)$
```

Comment: thanks, but didn't validate, plus, you seem to be using a repeating backref, which in this case won't work, it needs to validate 1-254 like an ip address http://regex101.com/r/xT5qS7

Comment: I don't know where you tested it, but if you try it in Notepad++, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

`([1-9]$|[1-9][0-9]$|[12][0-9][0-9]$)\.([0-9]$|[1-9][0-9]$|[12][0-9][0-9]$)\.([0-9]$|[1-9][0-9]$|[12][0-9][0-9]$)\.([1-9]$|[1-9][0-9]$|[12][0-9][0-9]$)`

Comment: ^(([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])\.([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])\.([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])\.([1-9][0-9]?|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-4])$)