# Regex to allow numeric integer values, a single zero but disable leading zeros

Tags: regex, validation, input, numbers

i need a **Regex to allow:**

- Numeric integer values, they can contain zeros or end in zero. (ie:
  36, 200, 105) in my case delimited by 6 digits max.
- Allow a single zero
- Dont allow leading zeros (ie: 048 shouldn't be valid)

Currently i have `/\d{1,6}/`  but im missing the last part, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use regex options `|` (like or). One option will be used to get simple 0 and the other to get all numbers starting by non 0.

`^([1-9][\d]*|0)$`

If you only want a maximum of 6 digits, you can use this:

`^([1-9][\d]{0,5}|0)$`

Comment: @HéctorLeón No need to wrap the single `\d` with the character class brackets and a non-capturing group is best since the grouping is only used here to make anchors work on both sides of each alternation. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47915302/3832970). And you actually need `^(?:[1-9]\d{0,5}|0)$` if you need to limit to 6 digits.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew oh thanks, i searched for a similar question, but didnt found it.
i just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430127/regex-numeric-range-with-no-leading-zeros), but wasn't exactly this issue

Comment: @GemTaylor I just edited last regex ;)